# publish to office clients using Powershell

Tags: powershell, office-integration

Is there a way to define the links to publish to office clients using Powershell?

To do this action through the UI you would go through:

Central Admin --> Manage Service Applications --> User Profile SA --> Manage --> My Site Settings --> Publish Links to Office Client Applications

Also, for some reason, all links from the publishing site, are being published to office clients, even if they are NOT on this list.
Any idea of what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: While I'd imagine there is a way, those properties didn't exist where I'd expect them to be. You should be able to access just about anything in the object model via PowerShell, the question becomes where is that data stored, so you know where to look. I expected them to be part of the service application properties, but alas they weren't there. If I get a chance later I'll look at the service instance and see if they're there.

Comment: PublishedLinksSyncedListLoader class is related to your question. I am not sure how to use it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.publishedlinkssyncedlistloader.aspx

Comment: Thanks Amit and webdes03. There are some good ideas to explore there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just implemented something along these lines for users of Window 7, it's not quiet what you asked, but it should get you there.

1. Create a shortcut to the desired document library, typically this will point at \webApplicationHostHeader@DavWWWRoot\ServerRelativeListUrl or  \webApplicationHostHeader@SSL\DavWWWRoot\ServerRelativeListUrl depending if you're working over SSL or not
2. $links = Join-Path $Home 'Links'
3. Copy your new .lnk file (shorcut) to $links
4. The user can now choose the list via the favourites section of the Save As dialog in Office clients.

You can of course create the shortcuts/.lnk files via powershell:

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortCut("$home\Links\SharePointList.lnk")
$targetPath = "\\my.site.host@DavWWWRoot\subsite\list"
$lnk.TargetPath = $targetPath
$lnk.Description = "Shortcut to SharePoint List"
$lnk.Save()
```